# Healthcheck for endpoints - quick and dirty version

Tags: rest, soap, groovy, soapui, postman

I have a few REST endpoints and few [asmx/svc] endpoints.
Some of them are GET and the others are POST operations.

I am trying to put together a quick and dirty , repeatable healthcheck sequence for finding if all the endpoints are responsive or if any are down.
Essentially either get a 200 or 201 and report error if otherwise.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

SOAPUI use internally apache http-client 4.1.1 version, you can use it inside a groovy script testStep to perform your checks.

Add a groovy script testStep to your testCase an inside use the follow code; which basically try to perform a GET against a list of URLs, if its returns http-status `200` or `201` its considered that is working, if http-status 405 (Method not allowed) is returned then it tries with POST and perform the same status code check, otherwise it's considered down.

*Note that some services can be running however can return for example `400` (BAD request) if the request is not correct, so think about if you need to rethink the way you want perform a check or add some other status codes to consider if the server is running correctly.*

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient

// urls to check
def urls = ['http://google.es','http://stackoverflow.com']

// apache http-client to use in closue
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()

// util function to get the response
def getStatus = {  httpMethod ->
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpMethod)
    // consume the entity to avoid error with http-client
    if(response.getEntity() != null) {
        response.getEntity().consumeContent();
    }

    return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
}

HttpGet httpget;
HttpPost httppost;

// finAll urls that are working
def urlsWorking =  urls.findAll { url ->
    log.info "try GET for $url"
    httpget = new HttpGet(url)
    def status = getStatus(httpget) 

    // if status are 200 or 201 it's correct
    if(status in [200,201]){
        log.info "$url is OK"
        return true
     // if GET is not allowed try with POST
    }else if(status == 405){
        log.info "try POST for $url"
        httppost = new HttpPost(url)
        status = getStatus(httpget) 

        // if status are 200 or 201 it's correct
        if(status in [200,201]){
            log.info "$url is OK"
            return true
        }

        log.info "$url is NOT working status code: $status"
        return false
    }else{
        log.info "$url is NOT working status code: $status"
        return false
    }
}

// close connection to release resources
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()

log.info "URLS WORKING:" + urlsWorking
```

This scripts logs:

```
Tue Nov 03 22:37:59 CET 2015:INFO:try GET for http://google.es
Tue Nov 03 22:38:00 CET 2015:INFO:http://google.es is OK
Tue Nov 03 22:38:00 CET 2015:INFO:try GET for http://stackoverflow.com
Tue Nov 03 22:38:03 CET 2015:INFO:http://stackoverflow.com is OK
Tue Nov 03 22:38:03 CET 2015:INFO:URLS WORKING:[http://google.es, http://stackoverflow.com]
```

Hope it helps,